# amp-analytics to track Facebook Pixel lead events

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, amp-html, amp-analytics

I am trying to implement form lead conversions using `amp-analytics` and facebook pixel.

I found examples on using `amp-analtics` with `facebook pixel` here;

[Github Amp Analytics Vendors](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/analytics-vendors.amp.html#L528)

However, this does not go into any detail on how the events are built up? Currently I have the following `amp` code;

```
<amp-analytics type="facebookpixel" id="facebook-pixel">
    <script type="application/json">
        {
        "vars": {
        "pixelId": "MYPIXELID"
        },
        "triggers": {
        "trackPageview": {
        "on": "visible",
        "request": "pageview"
        },
        "trackEvent": {
        "on": "amp-form-submit-success",
        "selector": "#instantQuoteForm",
        "request": "event",
        "vars": {
        "value": "1.00",
        "currency": "£"
        }
        }
        }
        }
    </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

So currently I want to track pageviews and form submissions completed through this page. Currently I have this generated through the facebook events manager interface;

[image: facebook screenshot ad manager]

Can anyone direct me to any kind of documentation for this?

**Update**

To update the event tracking seems to be coming through to the facebook manager console. Per the image below;

[image: event tracking page screenshot showing events]